# links to be made adjacent to logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to make the links adjacent to the image logo....
i am trying to make it in the same line....
i gave float left but its not working....
providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/hYGwH/14/embedded/result/

```
<li>
                            <a href="/product.html" >
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                My Files
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/solution.html">
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">Shared Files</a>
                            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/service.html"> 
                            <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">Create Files</a></li>
                        <li class="iphonePartnerLink">
                            <a href="/partner.html">
                            <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">Simply Notes</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/contact.html"> 
                            <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">Forms</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/contact.html"> 
                            <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">Drawing</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/contact.html"> 
                            <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo"   src="http://intra.defie.co/images/cube_inventory.png">
                                Presentation</a></li>
```

Comment: Where is the logo and you know you should only use an id once.

Comment: It isn't considered a fiddle, if you still haven't figured out how to link to external resources.

Comment: If your question is in regard to the case where the screen is maximized, I believe the issue is that your `container` is a fixed 940px and the `nav` width is too large to fit on the same line along with the logo. It wraps to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

The ul will not float beside the logo unless there is enough space for it horizontally. So if you make the window too small it will end up under the logo anyway. Decreasing the font-size of the a-tags in the navigation will allow it to fit on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the image before the anchor and floating the image left.  You will also need to clear the float on the next li or use a clearfix like overflow:hidden on the li. And of course clean up the multiple id problem.